Resizing root filesystem on lvm
I have a 24.04 server what is a VM and has run out of space in the root filesystem.
I have added more space through vCenter and used gparted to expand the partition. However, the root file system is still showing 100% of the previous partition size.
Any help would be great.
Thanks

Please add a screenshot of the Gparted. Are you using a VM and/or LVM? Your title says LVM, but your body of the question says VM. Have you searched this site for answers to similar question?

Well now after a few reboots it is now showing plenty of free space.
Thanks a bunch for the reply!

Please delete the question as it won't help anyone.

You'll be back. It sounds like log files filling up, check with the terminal command sudo journalctl --disk-usage, as your / fills up again

One cannot format or resize a disk's partitions while any of the disk's partitions is mounted. When a partition is mounted, the disk's metadata (partition info, cluster allocation info, ...) is cached in the kernel. parted, gparted, or other formatting tools also manipulate the disk's metadata.  Chaos follows.
Boot from another medium, your install disk in "Try" mode or a Live distribution.
Ensure that none of partitions of the target disk is mounted, and that any swap partition is not used. Use df, sudo umount and swapoff. Read man df umount swapoff free.

@waltinator That is not correct, especially not for LVM. LVM has supported online disk resizing since 1998. Even with traditional partitions, it's possible to ask the kernel to re-read the table. Relevant tools are cfdisk, partprobe and hdparm -z, making online resizing possible. In addition modern file systems such as EXT4, btrfs and xfs supports online resizing of the file system.
